# Why are my /usr/local/bin programs being copied to /usr/local/sbin?

Tags: bash

I can't seem to reproduce it now, but it seems that some of the programs I add to /usr/local/bin get added to `/usr/local/sbin`.

I noticed this because I wrote a bash script that seemed to me, for reasons that evaded me at the time, to simply not execute when I'd run it in a terminal. I used `whereas` and found an old copy with all contents commented out in `/usr/local/sbin`. After deleting the file from `.../sbin`, the working script in `.../bin` would execute when I ran it in the command line.

The output from `whereis` listed the file in `bin` before `sbin`. Why was the script from `sbin` taking priority? Also, any idea why the file was being copied to `sbin`? It is possible that I typoed "bin" to "sbin" multiple times while trying to fix the issue before realizing the problem, but I find that unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

No distribution I know of has any sort of mechanism that would copy any scripts you place in `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/local/sbin` or vice versa.

Are you aware that `bash` caches the pathnames of executed commands, and that sometimes you need to use the `hash` command to flush that cache?

If you had tried the script command without an explicit path before adding the working version to `/usr/local/bin`, the shell would have found the commented-out version in `/usr/local/sbin`, cached that pathname for it, and remembered it for the rest of the session. Even after adding the working version to `/usr/local/bin`, that shell session would have kept using the `/usr/local/sbin` version unless you ran `hash <scriptname>` (to redo the path search for `<scriptname>` only) or `hash -r` (to flush the entire path cache of that shell session).

The shell will also automatically re-run a full search for a previously hashed command if the command is no longer present in the hashed location, which explains why the expected behavior was restored once `/usr/local/sbin/<scriptname>` was deleted.

`whereis` is not an internal command of the `bash` shell, so it knows nothing about `bash`'s internal path cache. If my theory is correct, the `type <scriptname>` command (which is similar to `whereis` but built into `bash`) would have reported:

```
<scriptname> is hashed (/usr/local/sbin/<scriptname>)
```

To trigger the behavior you experienced, it would have been sufficient to first copy the commented-out version of the script to `/usr/local/sbin`, then attempt to run it once without an explicit path when no version of the script was yet present in `/usr/local/bin`. This would have required making the bin -> sbin typo only once.